# Error while pushing a Docker image into Cloud Foundry

Tags: docker

I am trying to push a Docker image (public) into Cloud Foundry, but got the
following error message.

```
FAILED
   Error restarting application: Server error, status code: 500, error code: 170011, message: Stager error: Failed to open TCP connection to stager.service.cf.internal:8888 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

Comment: Can you access the host stager.service.cf.internal?

Comment: No when I am trying to access it says unknown host

Comment: Are you using a hosted Cloud Foundry service? If so, which one (Pivotal Web Services, IBM Bluemix, etc...)? Or did you deploy it yourself?  If so, how -- can you link to some docs you followed to deploy it.  To use Docker on Cloud Foundry you will need to have the CF Diego runtime deployed as the backend runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, CF installed with bosh-lite according to pivotal docs.

commands:

```
cf enable-feature-flag diego_docker

cf push app1 -o localhost:5000/app1:1
```

docker registry setup:

```
docker pull registry:2
docker run --name reg2 -d --restart=always -p 5000:5000 registry:2
```

docker image app1 tagged and pushed w/o any issues.